# Sending a PHP response to specified webpage

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

I got a tiny question about PHP responses. I tried the tutorial provided by W3C School about Ajax and PHP. Everything worked fine. But now I want to send the response to another webpage instead of the webpage that triggers the event.

This is my AJAX Code:

```
function remote_function(int)
    {
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
        {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
        {
            document.getElementById("test_div").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
        }
        xmlhttp.open("GET","getCode.php?q="+int,true);
        xmlhttp.send();
    }
```

And this is my PHP code:

```
<?php
$q=$_GET["q"];
echo $q;
?>
```

And my HTML:

```
<a id="test_div" href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="remote_function(1);">0</a>
```

Looks like I need to send it to another webpage instead of just echoing the response. But I dont know how.

Thanks for any help! =)

Comment: Don't follow tutorials on W3Schools, it's a terrible website full of mistakes and misleads people. The key concept you have to understand is that you can't send a **reply** to the one who didn't ask for it. What you can do using your PHP code is make another **request** to some other website/page, wait for response and then return it back to original resource who used AJAX to contact your first page. Unless you clarify your question with what you want to do, you'll probably just get downvotes.

Comment: Also, try using jQuery or some wrapper for doing AJAX calls, for better browser compatibility